# RegEx Phone Number Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate a phone number this format  +905555555555.

How can I write a regex expression to test for this?

Comment: maybe not difficult for you, but if it wasn't for the OP he/she wouldn't post this question.

Comment: one "+" and 12 numbers. hint: escape the "+".

Comment: @jackJoe but to learn something he should try it. maybe he can post some examples he tried before.

Comment: @DanielB I agree with the example part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> one "+" and 12 numbers. hint: escape the "+".

```
^\+(90)\([2-5]{1}\)[0-9]{9}
```

or not starts with +;

```
\+(90)\([2-5]{1}\)[0-9]{9}
```

Comment: thank you but The number after +90.. 5.. must be [2-5]

like +90(2)642586989 or +90(3)642546987  +90(4)642546987  +90(5)642546987 you got it?

Comment: And starts with only +90

Comment: this is What I want Thanks again 

/^\+(90)[2-5]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;

Comment: I hope this also guides you to write some basic regex :)

Answer (score 1):

if you need it to start with a "+" and a "9" and 11 digits:

```
^[+]9\d{11}$
```

I recommend that you understand how regEx work, take a look at this usefull tester:
http://www.sweeting.org/mark/html/revalid.php

At the bottom they explain what each operator means.

Also there are all sort of examples at the internet.

EDIT: after reading the OP's comments, in order for the number to start with "+90" and then have 10 digits, you can use the following expression:

```
^[+]90\d{10}$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var test = "+905555555555";
var re = new RegExp(/^\+[0-9]{12}$/gi);

if(re.test(test))
{
alert("Number is valid");
} else {
alert("Number is not valid");
}
</script>
```

Check out this site for testing out your Regular Expressions: http://www.regextester.com/index2.html

And a good starting point to learn is here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

To cover your additional specifications use this:

```
^\+90\([2-5]\)\d{9}$
```

You definitely need the anchors `^` and `$` to ensure that there is nothing ahead or after your string. e.g. if you don't use the `$` the number can be longer as your specified 12 numbers.

You can see it [online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2toh2)

Answer (score 0):

If it's exactly that format then you could use something like: `/^\+\d{12}\z/`

If you'd like to allow some spaces/dashes/periods in it but still keep it at 12 numbers:
`/^\+(?:\d[ .-]?){12}\z/`
Then you could remove those other chars with:
`s/[ .-]+//g` (Perl/etc notation)

Answer (score 0):

> Adjusted a bit to answer question for a 12 digit regex.

```
// +905555555555 is +90 (555) 555-5555
let num = '+905555555555';
/^\+90\d{10}$/.test(num);
```